# How do you make the shell for this dinosaur egg dessert?

Tags: dessert

I found this very interesting dessert online:

[image: close-up] [image: several views]

How can I make this? In particular, how would you make the eggshell?

Comment: Welcome to the site and congrats for making the Hot Network Questions list! Don't forget to take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about this site. And would you please [edit] your post to include the source of your pictures, thanks?

Comment: That's literally too cute to eat. As someone with a pet bird, I would feel uncomfortable if this was served.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a version of the chocolate ball, only not intended for melting.

The standard chocolate ball is made by covering the inside of a spherical mold with tempered chocolate, then melting away the bottom so it can be placed over a scoop of ice cream. For the detailed process, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOjY61tlh98).

This version seems to use white chocolate instead. It is impossible to tell what the dots are, exactly, my best guess would be Oreo cookies ground to fine crumbles. An alternative would be ground (unpeeled) nuts like hazelnuts, or some poppy seed (that's probably not what the picture uses, but it would work well when you recreate the recipe).

The biggest problem would be the mold, I have no idea where you can source one. There are methods for making your own silicone molds from mixing caulking silicone with cornstarch, but I wouldn't consider them foodsafe. Maybe you can get away with using the paint-a-balloon method, but the shape won't be completely egglike. You may be able to hide this by using a more egg-shaped balloon, like the ones with a bit of a tube before the round body, and melting some more of the base away (where the balloon's tube is).

The egg in the picture looks like the ice cream is larger than the base. For that, you may need to work in two halves and glue them, which would be very fuddly work.

The nest looks simple, just use whatever form of chocolate sprinkles and shaved chocolate you have.

Comment: I don't know were she got it but my mother has a plastic mold that looks similar to the picture (might be one that a store brought one came in). She covers both halves in chocolate - lets them set, then puts ice cream of some sort in and the another chocolaty filling(maybe truffle) then presses the halves together seals with more of the shell chocolate. She makes this on easter.

Comment: The dots look like the dots you get in some products flavoured with vanilla

Comment: Use a 3D printer to make the mold.

Answer (score 5):

The eggshell is white chocolate with what looks like crushed cookie mixed in it to give the black speckles. The melted white chocolate mix is the poured into 2 molds (probably silicone) to give it that shape. Once cooled the two halves of the egg are joined together using a food glue or melting the edges of the egg halves and pressing them together.

It's served up on a bed of shaved chocolate in that picture but you could use crushed cookies, whole cookies, or anything edible that gives that effect.

Comment: This might be a good time of year to pick up easter egg moulds on clearance. The dinosaur inside was probably bought.